# 'NoneType' error while scraping youtube metadata (new to python)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm parsing the metadata of youtube videos. I'm getting this error:

```
{'title': 'Ethics in the age of technology | Juan Enriquez | TEDxBerlin', 'view': 66458, 'tags': 'TEDxTalks, English, Technology, Business, Ethics, International Affairs, Social Science, Society'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "youtubescraper.py", line 38, in <module>
    list_output.append(get_video_metadata("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + data[i][0])) # index the contents of the ith member of the list of lists
  File "youtubescraper.py", line 27, in get_video_metadata
    video_meta["view"] = int(''.join([ c for c in soup.find("span", attrs={"class": "view-count"}).text if c.isdigit() ]))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Although this happens after a variable number of entries get outputted, like here:

```
{'title': 'Ethics in the age of technology | Juan Enriquez | TEDxBerlin', 'view': 66454, 'tags': 'TEDxTalks, English, Technology, Business, Ethics, International Affairs, Social Science, Society'}
{'title': 'What is Technology Ethics?', 'view': 13905, 'tags': 'Santa Clara University, Markkula Center for Applied Ethics, Silicon Valley Ethics, technology ethics, human enhancements, artificial intelligence, synthetic biology'}
{'title': 'The ethical dilemma we face on AI and autonomous tech | Christine Fox | TEDxMidAtlantic', 'view': 63516, 'tags': 'TEDxTalks, English, United States, Technology, AI, Big Data, Big problems, Decision making, Government, Hack, Morality, Policy, Progress, Public Policy, Robots'}
{'title': 'Does Technology Need to Be Ethical?', 'view': 27446, 'tags': 'anil dash, technology, tech, ethics, facebook, mark zuckerberg, information, passwords, politics. aspen ideas, entrepreneur'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "youtubescraper.py", line 39, in <module>
    list_output.append(get_video_metadata("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + data[i][0])) # index the contents of the ith member of the list of lists
  File "youtubescraper.py", line 28, in get_video_metadata
    video_meta["view"] = int(''.join([ c for c in soup.find("span", attrs={"class": "view-count"}).text if c.isdigit() ]))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I'm curious (as a newbie) about 1. Why this NoneType error is happening (and particularly why I'm not getting a NoneType on the same entries each time) and 2. How I can resolve the NoneType errors.

Here is my complete code. First, my list of entries from the csv file (these are video ids and only put 50 entries for brevity but be forewarned that this program is really slow):

```
[['iiAirfn-lBI'], ['UISZx6K9enQ'], ['3oE88_6jAwc'], ['RoZ-WF5Z_1E'], ['RZB9PtUHfBE'], ['WMfbqHlrtEQ'], ['CR9kb6lvBmk'], ['duVoVZnWB2w'], ['1LyacmzB1Og'], ['X1mBUO8O654'], ['q-nhktqMoT4'], ['5YeK72q2CRQ'], ['AOqIiofqp3E'], ['IjRm6rxWyns'], ['phEuB6aYOho'], ['bZn0IfOb61U'], ['2SdpzTZTznw'], ['k1a2larfMIA'], ['S8a1DascnZg'], ['ixIoDYVfKA0'], ['X5WXSK_wm6s'], ['IFKhlxgoU58'], ['tzSoC_3y09s'], ['rTVta3BZfHU'], ['UbQlS6Rer6w'], ['EmzEnjrMB1Y'], ['Ji4Eu30VRoc'], ['pE5sF9SrnSI'], ['LYRKqnLeIDo'], ['p9VUBKiVM-k'], ['BxsJYEElcXY'], ['dBmUf5lQR98'], ['VYexAg2J6Kc'], ['eK_rhC25GAg'], ['cOCxbLaIu48'], ['_awIE_9vkV8'], ['P0fwUtChkd0'], ['cRx4ezY5KaY'], ['Hq--Sbdo9ls'], ['luabqeFCxzI'], ['mX0CpKWbAXU'], ['DkbXhhipcis'], ['LhzF-Y8xXBc'], ['5KZx81crb48'], ['KFgrns8dsis'], ['V3qVKndb7wA'], ['PoFAQi_DWsE'], ['3uYrPrn8Bzo'], ['YBIz8ouOMGk'], ['etr6sUHILKY']]
```

And the python:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import csv

# load my csv into memory
with open('ethcsvtest.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader) # data is a list of single-member lists with video ids

# get video metadata from beautifulsoup
session = HTMLSession()

def get_video_metadata(url): # defining the function to get video metadata
    response = session.get(url)
    # exe javascript
    response.html.render(sleep=1)

    soup = bs(response.html.html, "html.parser")

    video_meta = {}

    # get titles
    video_meta["title"] = soup.find("h1").text.strip()

    # Video Views
    video_meta["view"] = int(''.join([ c for c in soup.find("span", attrs={"class": "view-count"}).text if c.isdigit() ]))

    # Video Tags
    video_meta["tags"] = ', '.join([ meta.attrs.get("content") for meta in soup.find_all("meta", {"property": "og:video:tag"}) ])

    print(video_meta)

# loop through the array of ids, put the metadata dictionaries into a list, then turn the list of dictionaries into a dataframe
i = 0
list_output = []
while i < len(data):
    list_output.append(get_video_metadata("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + data[i][0])) # index the contents of the ith member of the list of lists
    i += 1
df = pd.DataFrame(list_output) # turn list of dictionaries into dataframe
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason or another, your `soup` cannot find any *span*s with `class == "view-count"`. You may debug it via e.g. printing the `soup` everytime, or using a visual debugger to see what's going on. I don't have the exact data, I can't debug :).

Here is a solution with a `try/except` block. It will try to find that span, but if it fails to find, we won't let it exit the program, but report it and continue:

```py
...
try:
    video_meta["view"] = int(''.join(c for c in soup.find("span", attrs={"class": "view-count"}).text if c.isdigit()))
except AttributeError:
    print(f"couldn't find the view count thing for this url: {url}")
    return  # exit the function, not the entire program via erroring as before!
...
```